# Call method from created jar file

Tags: java, jar

I created jar file using standart utulity `jar`. My jar contains single `.class` file, which code is listed below. I need to call method from this class. I found some instructions how to add jar for project in my IDE (i use Idea 14), but can't call a method. I tried to import class `import four.retCount`, bud idea marks word `four` as a mistake. 
What am i doing wrong? Is any way to solve this?

Code of class in jar:

```
package four;

public class retCount  {

     static public double Summ(double x, double n) {
        double res = 0;
        for(int k=1; k<=n; k++)
            res += Math.pow(-1, k+1)*(Math.sin(k*x)/k);
        return res;
    }

    static public double Func(double x){
        return x/2.;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your IDE doesn't recognize package `four` then it means it doesn't see it in its classpath/buildpath, or that your JAR doesn't have it. You would need to tell us something more about how you created that Jar and how you added it to your IDE.

Comment: Jars are basically zip files  - open up your jar file and confirm that it contains a folder called `four` with a class file called `retCount.class`.